# NoClassDefFoundError: com/squareup/javapoet/TypeName when including library

Tags: java, android, android-library, annotation-processing

I have been developing an annotation processor based library. When I run it as local library it works fine. for an example

```
implementation project(':dialogboot-annotations')
annotationProcessor project(':dialogboot-compiler')
```

but after publishing it to jCenter. It looks something like

```
implementation 'com.masum.dialogboot:dialogboot-annotations:1.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.masum.dialogboot:dialogboot-compiler:1.1.1'
```

but when I use this jCenter repo, it generates this below error but locally it works fine

> Error:Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while
>   constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor:
>   Provider dialogboot.compiler.DialogProcessor could not be
>   instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/squareup/javapoet/TypeName

Please help me out if anyone faced same problem after publishing the library in jCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by changing the android-maven-gradle-plugin version **2.0** instead of **1.1.4** in the root gradle dependencies

```
classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
```